# Most recent created subdirectory in directory (PHP)

Tags: php, html

For example - I have some subdirectory like this in ftp:

```
public_html/raports/pdf/
```

And in 'pdf' folder there are automatically created folders by month and year like: 07.2017, 08.2017, 09.2017 ... etc.

I would like to create href link to the last created or last modified folder in directory given above. How to do it in PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create links to files. Why would you like to link to the directory? If you want to link to files it would be nice to hide your file structure by dedicated script. This script may read your files by your id and returns the file. This should allow you create dedicated links and change their structure easily in the future.

Comment: I have something like this: $mail->addAttachment("pdf/07.2017/".str_replace('.','_',$row['nazwa']).".pdf");  and i would like to replace 07.2017 to automatically generated last catalog

Comment: Dinidu is right. You need to use database and query last added file.

Comment: there is no way to pull out timestamp of catalog from server?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you can save the time stamp and the folder name in a database table when the folder is being created and then when you construct the href string you can query for the latest timestamp and get the folder name match for that time stamp.

Comment: The timestamp must be save in database? It cant be 'downloaded' directly from FTP ?

Comment: It should be saved information about email and its attachments in database. Path to attachments should be resolved from database record ( date, file name or unique UUID, GUID or id )

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in node.js would use the `fs` module to get all file in the directory, then either:

- Map each file to a Date object built from the name
- Map each file to its "last modification date"

Then, a simple sort and you know which file is the most recent.
In both case however, it would be really easy to screw up the parsing and return the wrong file, like if you change the naming convention, or open a file in write mode.

Don't know the equivalent in PHP thought, but you will need access to a way to list the file in a given directory at the very least.